# Why I got Oracle error when I subtract one year from current date?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have this query on Oracle database 10g:

```
SELECT (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' YEAR) FROM DUAL;
```

It was running correctly, but today I got this error:

```
ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
01839. 00000 -  "date not valid for month specified"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I know how I can avoid such error, but my question why it's thrown?

Answer (score 8):

It is the expected behaviour; see the sixth bullet [in the datetime/interval arithmetic section](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i48042) of the documentation.

> When interval calculations return a datetime value, the result must be
>   an actual datetime value or the database returns an error. For
>   example, the next two statements return errors:
>
> ```
> SELECT TO_DATE('31-AUG-2004','DD-MON-YYYY') + TO_YMINTERVAL('0-1')
> FROM DUAL;
>
> SELECT TO_DATE('29-FEB-2004','DD-MON-YYYY') + TO_YMINTERVAL('1-0')
> FROM DUAL;
> ```
>
> The first fails because adding one month to a 31-day month would
>   result in September 31, which is not a valid date. The second fails
>   because adding one year to a date that exists only every four years is
>   not valid. However, the next statement succeeds, because adding four
>   years to a February 29 date is valid:
>
> ```
> SELECT TO_DATE('29-FEB-2004', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + TO_YMINTERVAL('4-0')
> FROM DUAL;
>
> TO_DATE('
> ---------
> 29-FEB-08
> ```

You can use [`add_months`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i48042), which has the opposite behaviour - which can also cause confusion sometimes. You need to decide which is most suitable for you.

Answer (score 2):

Because there was no Feb 29th in 2011

Comment: No, it isn't a bug. You could get the same if you subtract a month from March 30th